# Relative import structure

Tags: python

My program has a structure like so:

```
scripts/
     __init__.py
     mod1.py
     mod2.py
     sub1/
         __init__.py
         mod3.py
     sub2/
         __init__.py
         mod4.py
```

All programs are started with `mod1.py` which chooses which subsequent script (`mod3/mod4.py`) to run based off supplied system arguments. So the top level directory at import is `scripts/`.

Say I run my program such that `>mod1.py 3` executes `sub1.mod3`. Within `mod3` I need a function defined in `mod2` (this module holds reused code blocks for `mod3/mod4`).

When I try `from .. import mod2` I get the `ValueError` that I attempted a relative import beyond the top-level directory. I was referencing the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) on the syntax, and if we compare them to my situation, `mod3.py` would be the current module (after `mod1.py`) called it.

What is wrong with how I am trying to do relative imports?

**mod1.py**:

```
import sys

def imp(module):
    m = __import__(module) # equivalent to import module as m
    m.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mods = {'3': 'sub1.mod3',
            '4': 'sub2.mod4'}

    imp(mods[sys.argv[1]])
```

**mod3.py**

```
from .. import mod2  # fails
import mod2  # works; guessing since import considers mod1 location top-level
.
.
.
def start():
    # do stuff
```

Comment: `mod2` is not in `scripts.sub2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> All programs are started with mod1.py which chooses which subsequent script (mod3/mod4.py) to run based off supplied system arguments. So the top level directory at import is scripts/.

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) (6.4.2 Intra-package Referencing):

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "__main__", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports.

hence you must use absolute imports in your files.

So your code should read

```
from scripts.mod2 import X
```

or

```
from scripts import mod2
```

Additionally, I'm not sure why you want to do this.
It would be simpler to keep both modules in separate packages, and load them with an `if` condition, while keeping the files all in the same directory, sans the `__init__.py`:

```
if sys.argv[1] == '3':
    import mod3
elif sys.argv[2] == '4':
    import mod4
```

If you must keep them in separate folders, use this strcture:

```
scripts/
    mod1.py
    pkg/
        __init__.py
        mod2.py
        sub1/
            __init__.py
            mod3.py
        sub2/
            __init__.py
            mod4.py
```

With this structure your relative imports should work. Importing would then be:

```
if sys.argv[1] == '3':
    from pkg.sub1 import mod3
elif sys.argv[2] == '4':
    from pkg.sub2 import mod4
```

It is worthy to note that, regardless of what part of a library or package you import, the entire package gets imported anyway - it's just not all available in the scope.

Comment: You should include a link to the documentation source.

Comment: When I do either of those, I get `'no module named scripts'`. Again, just calling `import mod2` works, even though its in `mod3/mod4`; but I should be able to do what you've said; don't know why I cant.

Comment: I need to keep them in their own directories, so not using relative imports doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Fair enough - but still, why do they need to be one module?

Comment: Also, using relative imports is not advised by the Python style guide, so stay clear of it whenever you can.

Comment: What does creating the new `pkg/` do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152259/discussion-between-nlsdfnbch-and-datta).